# .htpasswd file leads to server error?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

**Code behind .htaccess file** :

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd" 
require valid-user
```

**Code behind .htpasswd file** :

```
user121:$apr1$bVI1xobF$2ius9YiPaElsFDjD2DK5/0
```

I login with correct credentials and this is what i get every time i login :

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
```

**Update** :

Apache Error Log :

```
[Fri Jun 06 20:42:30.503554 2014] [authn_file:error] [pid 7536:tid 1760] (OS 2)
The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client ::1:58747] AH01620: Could
not open password file: C:/xampp/apache/.htpasswd, referer: 
http://localhost/manage/articles/
```

> I cannot place the file in xampp/apache folder on my webhost?

Comment: What does your Apache error log say?

Answer (score 2):

The error log shows you are using a wrong path to the .htpasswd file:

> Could not open password file: C:/xampp/apache/.htpasswd

That tells you it's not located in C:/xampp/apache. Make sure to use the correct path in your .htaccess file. E.g. if your .htpasswd is located under C:/xampp/apache/htdocs/myproject/.htpasswd, set it as such.

```
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/apache/htdocs/myproject/.htpasswd
```

(Although it's best practice *not* to put .htpasswd inside your htdocs/httpdocs, I just used this path as an example.)

If you're sure the path is correct, since you seem to be on a Windows installation, make sure the file is actually called .htpasswd. Windows cannot do this from the Explorer (it forbids to create an "extension only" file), you must do this from a command-line based tool. If you created the .htpasswd in Notepad or such, the file is most likely now actually called .htpasswd.txt, use a command-line to rename it to .htpasswd:

```
C:\> cd C:\xampp\apache
C:\xampp\apache> move .htpasswd.txt .htpasswd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Mac and this worked for me:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/htpasswd -cb /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/.htpasswd admin password
```